# React components not respecting legend position configuration

Tags: gooddata

Is there any reason why my chart legends are always appearing on the right?  My config looks like this:

`legend: {
    enabled: true,
    position: 'bottom'
}`

Setting `enabled` to `false` causes the legend to disappear as expected, but changing the `position` has no effect.

This is using `@gooddata/react-components` `5.2.0-alpha17`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config looks correct. Please share the code for the whole component and we will have a look at it. This is unlikely the problem, but please try to use a stable version instead of alpha. Current stable version is 5.1.0.

Please check you are importing your styles correctly

```
import '@gooddata/react-components/styles/css/main.css';
```

This snippet should work:

```
                <PieChart
                    projectId={projectId}
                    measures={measures}
                    config={{
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            position: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }}
                />
```

You can find more information about chart legends in the [official documentation](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/chart_config.html#change-legend-visibility-and-position)

Comment: The code is a little bit less straightforward than that, since we are embeding in an Angular 2 app.  We use the `react` and `reactDOM` APIs to dynamically create an render the components.

The element create code is:
`react.createElement(this.chartType, props);`
And the `props` is shaped like so:
```
export interface ChartProps {
    ...
    config: {
        legend: {
            enabled: boolean,
            position: string
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Do you know if version `5.1.0` supports the `sortBy` functionality?  I think it was not present in `5.0.0`.

Comment: This should work even in Angular. Can you please post the whole code including this.chartType and props? Not just the shape but also the values. I can double check your exact example.
sortBy support comes in 5.1.0 and we just released 5.2.0.

Comment: Here's a gist with some of that info.  Please let me know if you would like more detail.  
https://gist.github.com/Blackbaud-StewartStephens/f65c5532539cfd6def595d4d627b96b4

Comment: I updated to 5.2.0 stable and this is now working for me.